# Quality of review process

Tags: discussion

I'm just curious if anyone actually over looks the quality of the "review" tab. I recently started to contribute and have noticed that there are others that regularly contribute, but are doing so at a lightning fast pace.

I have a doubt that it is actually being done properly, in fact I've come across a few "new posts" that had spelling mistakes or formatting issues, while they were minor it makes me wonder.

Also, having been a victim of a question being incorrectly closed myself - the same people appear to be blindly voting. When I raised the fact it shouldn't have been closed here, it was voted to be re-opened. I've voted to keep some questions opened that were borderline, even went as far to edit them to salvage it but they were ultimately closed and my edit rejected?

I'm thinking that the review section has created a culture of blindly reviewing posts, edits, votes in efforts to just rack up points without merit.

I don't think I'm completely wrong on this, I've seen it a few times already.  I don't believe everyone is to blame here, but you cannot tell me that with the speed the queues are being cleared that there is actually any quality to the work being put in.

After having witnessed yet another closing to a question that I voted to keep opened (new user, the post could have been edited and there was an answer) I am proposing the following:

1. Limits per **MONTH** on how many times a person can vote

Note: This will force people to read more carefully and fully consider the questions they vote to close.

2. Lower the current limit of how many times a person can vote per **DAY**

Note: Again will prevent blind voting and allow questions to stay open long enough for someone to answer or properly edit the question.

3. Set a time delay after 3 consecutive reviews by the same person with "No Action Needed"

Note: This will address the many "new user" posts or "first answer" posts that I've seen that require obvious adjustments that are just not implemented.

I think the above is a good start to a) allow more members to contribute b) allowing questions to remain open for a reasonable amount of time c) prevent people from blindly clearing the queues.

---

**Can a moderator please have a look at the user Keyul Shah**

He is not reviewing new posts properly - most of them are "No Action Needed" but clearly need editing. Some have been subsequently edited, some posts have obvious formatting issues example: [Magento. Extremely low First Byte and load time](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62233/magento-extremely-low-first-byte-and-load-time)

Comment: There's definitely patterns. I recently posted about this because it's still happening: https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2688/reviewers-please-stop-pressing-looks-ok-when-its-not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I personally are tired of stupid questions. If I don't understand a question, because I invest more time in reviewing it, than the OP to ask it, I close it. At least it feels like it. Normally I leave a comment, because I don't understand the question.

And I can tell at least for me, that I'm wondered from time to time, which questions are closed. So I understand your point.

Comment: I agree that questions without any thought or work done are frustrating and should be closed. I'm happy that you agree and understand my point.

Comment: I just skip the questions Iam not able to understand, usually there is someone who will be able to understand it or help to make it understandable.
I remember questions I edited to make them better understandable, when others already voted for close.

Answer (score 5):

I am one of the people who only have a light view ower the questions,
 I participate there from time to time as I think we dont have enough reviewers anyway.
Iam not perfect in grammar, and not good in spelling.
I usually care about if the question makes sense and is answerable and then also give an upvote.

Comment: Maybe spelling and grammar is a bit over the top - I don't agree that we don't have enough reviewers, they aren't given a chance because the same person/people have made it a mission to clear them out within seconds of them arriving in the queue.  You are not one of the offenders, what you are doing is exactly what the review process should be.