# Reviewers: Please stop pressing "Looks OK" when it's not

Tags: support, answers, flagging

I have flagged several non-answers using the Not an Answer flag. They are disputed because some (often the same) reviewers are selecting "Looks OK" in review:

- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/337071/ (Deleted now)
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/298355/ (Deleted now)
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/361218/ (Deleted now)
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/337481/ (Deleted now)
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/351183/ (Deleted now)
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/366633/ (Deleted now)

  - The comment is an attempt to add a second answer. User probably thinks that this is a forum.
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/279483/ (Deleted now)
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/341017/ (Deleted now)
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/357707/ (Deleted now)

  - Has another non-answer on the same question that was reviewed as Looks OK in the past. I have a pending flag on that one.
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/347917/ (Deleted now)

---

Update: It looks like a mod or someone has taken a look at these and deleted all of them.

---

I have a few others pending, but I think that they will suffer a similar fate as only one of my flags did anything. Also of note, several of these have been reviewed as Looks OK in First Answers and Late Answers.

I understand that once in a while reviewers can miss things, but this is clearly a pattern. This states that these posts should have been flagged and deleted: [What should I flag and what I shouldn't flag](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1014/what-should-i-flag-and-what-i-shouldnt-flag)

Under "What should you definitely flag":

> Answers that are not answers (other questions, "thank you" answers, ...)

These are clearly not answers. Can reviewers please follow the guidelines? And can we get these posts deleted?

Comment: I'm confused. Your account seems not to have written a single post on this site before, unless I'm seeing something wrong. Anyone who reviewed the posts would need enough points to do so, which means that they've contributed far more in terms of publishing upvoted content. I wonder if you can give us some more background about this Meta question?

Comment: I don't understand what point you're trying to make about reputation and upvoted content. Some of these reviewers are incorrectly saying blatant non-answers are answers, contradicting this site's policies.

Comment: Is it fair to say that It's their site more than it's yours? They earned the reputation required to make review decisions. If you can provide more context about your post, for example the reason why you are posting it, then I think it would be more appreciated. Also I looked at the first example that you gave, and it doesn't seem that it actually got a "looks ok" review at all: https://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/335729/timeline?filter=NoVoteDetail. The  corresponding question got "No action needed" https://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/335725/timeline, but no review on the answer?

Comment: *Is it fair to say that It's their site more than it's yours? They earned the reputation required to make review decisions.* This is a non-sequitur. Higher reputation does not equate to a more correct review. They are objectively wrong reviews because they have stated that a non-answer is an answer. Regarding the first answer, it is now deleted.

Comment: A First Questions reviewer even Looks OKed a [blatantly off-topic question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/first-questions/207301). What is going on here?

Comment: @user1271772 That appears to be an ad hominem attack. OP raises legitimate concerns about the moderation of this site regardless their participation.

Comment: It wasn't an attack

Comment: @user16217248 For "what is going on," probably robo-reviewing (blindly pressing Looks OK or whatever is the zero-effort option). For the question, it also smells awfully spammy to me. However, there's no actual spam link, so I've flagged it as "blatantly off topic."  Maybe reviewers will pay attention in the close queue...

Comment: Maybe this user has learned better though? The user's review history indicates a vote for closure on that exact question today. If you flagged it, good.

Comment: I think this site needs some *STOP! Look and listen* audits.

Comment: @user16217248 Maybe, but those are generated by the site, and I'm not sure the site is big enough to generate them accurately. Besides, even those are easy enough to avoid if you game the system. It seems to be a small group of repeat offenders, so I think a couple of review-suspensions/mod messages/actual suspensions would help.

Comment: @user16217248 At any rate, I can downvote now. We'll just let the roomba get that question.